# What timezone is that stack-status page on, and can we have it behave normal(ish)?

Tags: feature-request, maintenance, timezone, stackstatus

The latest maintenance announcement has as a title:

> Planned maintenance scheduled for Tuesday, August 23, 2022 at 00:00-03:00 AM UTC (Monday, August 22, 8:00-11:00 PM US/EDT)

When I visit [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net) I see the following announcement about the scheduled maintenance:

[image: Screenshot of stackstatus.net showing the indicated time for maintenance being August 23, 2022 | 02:00am - 05:00am]

This is a third timezone being used, rather then the UTC or Eastern time that is currently used as a standard. Can we make stackstatus fall in line please?

Also bonus points if you could have the scheduled maintenance on stackstatus link to the MSE post.

P.S. Kudo's for adding the planned maintenance to the status page this time!

Comment: It's your local time, though that could of course be made more obvious / consistent.

Comment: Should have thought about that @Glorfindel, DST throwing me off once more.

Comment: While having the date/time shown in the browser's local timezone is useful, it would be helpful to also show date/time values in UTC, as that's the timezone SE operates in and how its listed in announcements and postmortems.

Comment: It's local time except in the UK where it's equivalent to GMT during our summertime (BST).